# Why does Blender tell me this mp4 is an unsupported format when open it in the VSE?

Tags: file-format

I have a video that I shot with my Samsung Galaxy 7, and I saved it to my computer. When I open it in Blender VSE, it tells me that it's an unsupported format. I have the latest, 2.78a. Am I doing something wrong? Should I render it in something else?

Comment: How are you opening it? Does the video play well in other software in your computer? If nothing else works try converting it to another format with a conversion software like handbrake or similar

Comment: Also check that it isn't a corrupt file when transferred to computer.